# I/O errors during BLKDISCARD on Linux Dell R720 with SAS Seagate Nytro

Tags: ssd, linux-kernel, sas, trim

I have a Dell R720 with PERC H310 Mini (LSI 2008 MegaRAID) controller which I have just loaded with 4 new Seagate Nytro XS1600LE70045 1.6TB SSD, configured as individual disks for Linux software raid.  (please ignore the argument of software vs. hardware raid for the moment, the explanation is offtopic)

I can read and write all the drives nicely with no errors.   I can partition and format them with Ext4 successfully, but during the ext4 formatting I get one kernel error:

```
[15962.216694] sd 0:0:3:0: [sdd] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[15962.216698] sd 0:0:3:0: [sdd] tag#0 CDB: Unmap/Read sub-channel 42 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00
[15962.216699] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 27469824
```

The `smartctl -a` does not report any errors from the drive itself.

This explodes into thousands of kernel errors when I assemble a raid device and try to format that.  The errors seem to be occurring like a timeout, appearing in the kernel log about 1 second apart, and lagging up all other communications to the drive, including smartctl commands.

Using strace, it appears that the BLKDISCARD on the plain partition fails and then mkfs.ext4 doesn't try again.  But, when it runs BLKDISCARD on an md device the BLKDISCARD returns 0, and then it issues more BLKDISCARD commands and meanwhile the kernel driver is having them all fail.  My kernel is Linux 4.19.23, x86_64

Aside from the annoying problem of having to wait tens of minutes for all the I/O errors to flow (the mkfs.ext4 eventually succeeds) I'm wondering if this means something in my chain of hardware or software is not able to correctly issue BLKDISCARD commands at all?  In that case, SSDs might not perform that well.

Does anyone know if a Dell R720 with PERC H310 Mini and SAS Nytro drives (which are 12GB/sec connected to a 6GB/sec controller in this case) running Linux 4.19.23 would be a problem for issuing BLKDISCARD (trim) commands?

**Update**

The firmware version of the PERC H310 is 20.13.3-0001.

TRIM is a SATA command not likely to be supported by SAS drives.  The SAS equivalent is "UNMAP", which can be called from the command-line utility `sg_unmap`.  The sg_unmap command also fails on my system with the same I/O error.

Also tested with Kernel 4.19.307, but no change.

#### sg_unmap

```
$ sg_unmap --lba=1 --num=1 -f /dev/sdb
unmap: transport: Host_status=0x07 [DID_ERROR]

sg_unmap failed: Transport error
$ dmesg | tail
[ 1284.253975] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 1284.253979] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Unmap/Read sub-channel 42 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00
[ 1284.253981] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
```

#### lshw

```
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Xeon E5/Core i7 IIO PCI Express Root Port 2c
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.2
             version: 07
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci msi pciexpress pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:24 ioport:f000(size=4096) memory:dd000000-ddffffff
           *-storage
                description: RAID bus controller
                product: MegaRAID SAS 2008 [Falcon]
                vendor: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: scsi0
                version: 03
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: storage pm pciexpress vpd msi msix bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=megaraid_sas latency=0
                resources: irq:26 ioport:fc00(size=256) memory:ddffc000-ddffffff memory:ddf80000-ddfbffff memory:dd000000-dd01ffff
...
              *-disk:1
                   description: SCSI Disk
                   physical id: 0.1.0
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.1.0
                   logical name: /dev/sdb
                   size: 1490GiB (1600GB)
                   capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
                   configuration: guid=f46bd41c-6e46-4c0c-b19f-ea2d3fe79f86
```

#### Syscall Traces:

`strace mkfs.ext4` on a single partiton:

```
ioctl(3, BLKALIGNOFF, 0)                = 0
ioctl(3, BLKIOMIN, 4096)                = 0
ioctl(3, BLKIOOPT, 0)                   = 0
ioctl(3, BLKPBSZGET, 4096)              = 0
ioctl(3, BLKSSZGET, 512)                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
access("/sys/fs/ext4/features/lazy_itable_init", R_OK) = 0
open("/dev/sdd4", O_RDONLY|O_EXCL)      = 3
stat("/dev/sdd4", {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0660, st_rdev=makedev(8, 52), ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, BLKDISCARDZEROES, 0)           = 0
pread(3, "01\245\5\0\200\211\26\231y \1\256\6.\26%1\245\5\0\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\2\0\0\0"..., 1024, 1024) = 1024
close(3)                                = 0
access("/var/lib/e2fsprogs", W_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/dev/sdd4", O_RDWR|O_EXCL)        = 3
stat("/dev/sdd4", {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0660, st_rdev=makedev(8, 52), ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, BLKDISCARDZEROES, 0)           = 0
ioctl(3, BLKROGET, 0)                   = 0
mmap(NULL, 376832, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f06c4527000
ioctl(3, BLKDISCARD, {0, 7ffc9a2a78a0}) = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
pwrite(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 3072, 1024) = 3072
stat("/dev/random", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0666, st_rdev=makedev(1, 9), ...}) = 0
open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
fcntl(4, F_GETFD)                       = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
fcntl(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
getuid()                                = 0
getppid()                               = 19277
read(4, "(=\233R-\333\371\3*}\357\205\226\31&t", 16) = 16
close(4)                                = 0
gettid()                                = 19281
stat("/dev/random", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0666, st_rdev=makedev(1, 9), ...}) = 0
open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
fcntl(4, F_GETFD)                       = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
fcntl(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
getuid()                                = 0
getppid()                               = 19277
read(4, "\264\27\315\3155X\376\220\355\347\353\366\26\237\214!", 16) = 16
close(4)                                = 0
gettid()                                = 19281
write(1, "Creating filesystem with 3781099"..., 65Creating filesystem with 378109952 4k blocks and 94712112 inodes
```

`strace mkfs.ext4` on an md device:

```
ioctl(3, BLKDISCARDZEROES, 0)           = 0
pread(3, "\0\0\24\0\0\360O\0003\377\3\0\257\2N\0\365\377\23\0\0\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\2\0\0\0"..., 1024, 1024) = 1024
close(3)                                = 0
access("/var/lib/e2fsprogs", W_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/dev/md125", O_RDWR|O_EXCL)       = 3
stat("/dev/md125", {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0660, st_rdev=makedev(9, 125), ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, BLKDISCARDZEROES, 0)           = 0
ioctl(3, BLKROGET, 0)                   = 0
uname({sys="Linux", node="cildat1", ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, BLKDISCARD, {0, 7ffd8c6d0930}) = 0
write(1, "Discarding device blocks: ", 26Discarding device blocks: ) = 26
write(1, "   4096/5238784", 15   4096/5238784)         = 15
write(1, "\10\10\10\10\10\10\10\10\10\10\10\1) = 150\10", 15
ioctl(3, BLKDISCARD, {1000000, 7ffd8c6d0930}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in RAID mode (IR mode), LSI 2008 based cards (ie: PERC H3xx) do not support trim/discard passdown. You need to reflash your card with a firmware in IT mode to enable trim/discard.

However, be aware that:

- you will lose official support from the vendor
- you will lose access to any HW-RAID modes
- all data already stored on the disks/array will be lost
- if anything goes wrong during reflash, you can brick your card

So be careful and think twice if you really need trim/discard or if you can simply reserve some more scratch space on the SSD for garbage collection to work.

Comment: The drives are configured as JBOD, not RAID.  Is "IR Mode" a controller-wide setting?  Can I turn it off?

Comment: JBOD mode still writes controller-specific metadata and engages the controller "RAID mode". You can try to use non-RAID mode as described [here](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000133007/how-to-convert-the-physical-disks-mode-to-non-raid-or-raid-capable). *Before trying be sure to understand that any data already stored on the disks can be lost*, so use with care.

Comment: I've confirmed that the drives are in "Non-RAID" state.  I also installed the sg_unmap utility and it also gives an I/O error.  Also that the firmware is "20.13.3-0001"

Comment: So I found the rest of the answer.  The "IR" mode is the firmware, and to change it to "IT mode" you need to re-flash the card with LSI firmware, but if you want to use it in a Dell R720 you need to further tweak the firmware to use a known PCI ID that Dell likes, or it won't boot.  (https://fohdeesha.com/docs/perc.html)  If you update your answer to include these details I'll mark it as accepted.